# un-sync iPhone and iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod-touch

I bought an iPod touch first. I registered it with iTunes, gave it a name, etc. All was well, it synced when I connected it, made backups, etc.

Eventually I got an iPhone. I didn't need to register it with iTunes, it found my iPod touch data somehow. I don't think it ever asked me to give it a name. And the most annoying part, is that it syncs all the apps I put on the iPod Touch with the iPhone, and vice-versa.

How do I separate these two devices?

Answer (score 2):

If the two devices are named the same it will backup/restore the same items. My recommendation is to rename one of your devices and a new profile will be created for it.

Comment: I thought this worked but it didn't. I renamed the second iDevice, syncing both of them and set up apps the way I wanted. Then I installed a new app on the second iDevice and the next time I sync'ed the first it had the new app installed on it.